# Unable to go last page and antepenultimate of the bootstrap laravel pagination

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, pagination

Before I create one laravel 8 application and I was using the bootstrap pagination, but I was getting about 40 rows from my database and the pagination works fine, but now I created another application and now I have 300020 rows in my database and now the pagination is bigger than before, but the problem is that if try to go to the last page as we can see in the picture below I can't do it, I only can go to a minor page than it.

[image]

I don't know why the pagination can't agree me go to the last page and antepenultimate.

[image]

I'm using the `links()` method.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Employees</title>
    <link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body>
    {{ $employees->total() }}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <table class="table">
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <th>Emp_no</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Hire Date</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        @foreach($employees as $employee)
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ $employee->emp_no }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $employee->first_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $employee->last_name }}</td>
                                <td>{{ $employee->hire_date }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <hr>
                {{ $employees->links() }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Bootstrap JS, jquery y popper compiled -->
    <script src="{{ mix('js/app.js') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code from the controller:

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $employees = Employee::query()->Paginate(5);

        return view('employee.index', compact('employees'));
    }
}
```

My model code, I import a table to my database:

```
class Employee extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'employees';
    protected $primaryKey = 'emp_no';
}
```

I like test my apps when there will be thousands of data. Well guy if you have any idea about how fix this problem, I will appreciate it. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the `html` due to the lack of space in the central `div`. Then I updated my code and now I only have one column:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-hover">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <th>Emp_no</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Hire Date</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach($employees as $employee)
                        <tr>
                            <td>{{ $employee->emp_no }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $employee->first_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $employee->last_name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $employee->hire_date }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <hr>
            {{ $employees->links() }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```